# swagger editor reference definition inside another definition

Tags: swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

Inside my definitions I'm using inheritance.  In the example below, the PERSON-PATCH properties are coming in without issue.  Now I want to take the PERSON-BIO properties and show that's a sub-object inside the PersonGet.   I can't figure out the syntax to do that.

```yaml
PersonBio:
  type: object
  properties: &PERSON-BIO
    nickname:
      type: string
      description: The nickname for the Person
    ... other properties chopped out ...
  minProperties: 1

PersonGet:
  type: object
  properties:
    <<: *PERSON-PATCH
    ident:
      type: integer
      format: int32
      description: The SQL ident of the Person
    bio:
      <<: *PERSON-BIO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, just figured this out;

```yaml
PersonGet:
  type: object
  properties:
    <<: *PERSON-PATCH
    bio:
      $ref: '#/definitions/PersonBio'
```